# How do I get the CoreData Debug argument to output to the console?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, debugging, sqlite, core-data

According to [Apple documentation on debugging Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002320-SW15) it says we should be able to pass an argument to the application which will output the SQL core data sends to SQLite.

I have gone into the arguments tab of my executable in XCode and specified the arguments:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

However, I see no SQL in the console.  I then tried to use this parameter in the CoreDataBooks application provided by Apple just in case there was some other issue in MY program.

Even in Apple's example I get no SQL output in the console.

Am I doing something wrong? Is Apple's documentation wrong? Should I be looking someplace other than the console? Has anyone else had success with this argument?

**UPDATE:** Apple has since fixed the output bug with newer releases of XCode; however, to be clear on the final solution:

**The arguments are two separate arguments and should be entered in the arguments tab as such.  -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug is one parameter and the value 1 is the second parameter.**

Comment: I think you will find the answer in the following link: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/11/debugging-core-data-on-the-iphone.html Cheers :)

Comment: SQLDebug is supported on device and on the simulator. I encourage you to change the correct answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're happy to take the time to write a grammatically-erroneous and snobbish response, but you won't update the answer for the good of the community. You may be paid to write software, but I wouldn't call you professional.

Comment: Do you believe the incorrect answer is better for historical context? Why not change the answer? I respect your decision to leave the answer incorrect if you have a reasonable purpose, but doing so out of spite is harmful to the community.

Comment: It is still relevant. This was the top hit when searching for the CoreData debugging arguments. Thus, it is important for the answer to be correct.

Comment: @richardsun's answer (which has 13 upvotes) is correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14374/discussion-between-radesix-and-heath-borders)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

XCode 4 (final) seems to be inconsistent.

Using one argument works on the device, but fails in the simulator:

`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`

Using two arguments works on the device and in the simulator:

`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug`

`1`

Comment: As of XCode 4.x, using a single argument such as -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1 works in the simulator. The same result still occurs if you use two separate arguments.

Comment: This works as a single argument for the simulator in Xcode 6.

Answer (score 5):

Are you entering those as a single argument? It should be 2 arguments: "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug" and "1".

More Info: 
You're actually overriding a "default" here. Take a look at the [Apple Docs on argument-based defaults](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Concepts/DefaultsDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000718-96930) for more information. You'll see that the name and value are 2 separate arguments.

Comment: Jesse, even if I make these two separate arguments I still get no extra output in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I too banged my head against this for a while.  Turns out SQLDebug with Core Data is not supported on iPhone yet.  It is tracked by Apple bug ID [6868205](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/112/wo/j2wxWIapgEsau7DHNStox0/7.56).

Comment: SQLDebug is supported on device and on the simulator. I encourage you to change the correct answer.