# Time taken for Core-data fetch with NSPredicates filtering  ~ WEIRD 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data

So, I am trying to fetch around 2000 objects from core-data and trying to find out which would be the fastest way to fetch them.

**Without NSPredicates:**

When I add this block (below), the `if` statement takes 90% of the total time taken to execute, which is understandable, and so I comment it out.

```
Block {

    NSError *error;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context =  <#Get the context#>;

    // The IF block

/*   if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);
    }
*/
       // The block above takes 90% of the total time of fetch

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *theEntity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                  entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:theEntity];

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];    

    }
```

**With NSPredicates:**

I set the predicate as

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"handle == %@",handle];
```

and perform the same fetch as shown in `Block()`

It can be seen that the overall time is the exact opposite -it's around 90% faster if I use the `IF BLOCK`  ~ 6 seconds.

Otherwise, if that block is commented, the fetching time is a LOT ~ 3 minutes.  This happens only when set a `predicate` for the `fetchRequest`.

Can someone please explain ?

That is,

```
 /*
 Save + straight fetch = slow, due to saving. 
 Straight fetch - pretty fast. 
 Predicate fetch, slow. 
 Save + predicate fetch, much faster? 
 */
```

Comment: show more code. What is "The IF block"? How do you use that block? And how do you create your NSFetchRequest?

Comment: So let me get this straight because I find the question a bit confusing as written. Save + straight fetch = slow, due to saving. Straight fetch - pretty fast. Predicate fetch, slow. Save + predicate fetch, much faster?

Comment: @jrturton YEP !! That is right !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Guesswork, hopefully educated) After a save the context can perform a predicated fetch directly against the database as it knows that there are no objects whose changes have not been written to the DB yet. Without the save, it has to fetch against the DB and also any extant objects who may have unsaved changes.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm trying to understand the inner workings of Core Data, it helps to turn on the [SQL Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822906/how-do-i-get-the-coredata-debug-argument-to-) with the following argument:

```
    -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

This will print out all the SQL statements that are being executed, so you could really see the difference.  It's also possible (just a theory) that right after the save, the persistent store (or perhaps just indexes) are still in cache, making an indexed (predicate) fetch faster.

At any rate, the SQL Debug will show you what statements are executed and when - might lead to some optimizations in your model for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The efficiency gains have nothing to do with the way you perform your fetch.

The reason for your delays is that you are **saving** in the if block. This is a quite expensive operation. If you do it 2000 times it might well take several seconds or even more.

When you fetch entities from the persistent store it does not make sense to save, only if you were to modify these entities. And even then you would try to keep your calls to save to a minimum.

Comment: Yes, I get it. That is why I take it of in my code without `NSPredicates` and it takes about 0.02 sec. But, when I am using NSPredicates to filter my fetch, and the `IF BLOCK is present`, it takes 0.02 seconds for a fetch... and `without the IF BLOCK` it takes 0.25 seconds for a fetch.   So, when I have 2000 fetches, you can imagine the time it takes !!! It's weird right ?