# What is the more efficient way of sorting and filtering Core Data relationships?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Assuming I have a Podcast entity, which has-many Episodes, I'm confused as to which of these would be the preferred option for culling and sorting:

```
// Always work with the relationship property
- (NSSet*)unfinishedEpisodes {
  NSArray* episodes = self.episodes.allObjects;

  NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(PodcastEpisode* episode, NSDictionary* bindings) {
    return !episode.isFinished;
  }];

  NSArray* unfinishedEpisodes = [episodes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

  return [NSSet setWithArray:unfinishedEpisodes];
}

- (NSArray*)unfinishedEpisodesSortedByAge {
  NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];

  return [self.unfinishedEpisodes.allObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}
```

or

```
// Fetch specific sets of data as needed
- (NSArray*)unfinishedEpisodes:(NSArray*)sortDescriptors {  
  NSFetchRequest* fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Episode"];

  NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"podcast == %@ AND playcount == 0", self];
  fetch.predicate = predicate;

  fetch.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

  NSArray* results = [KRTDataManager.sharedManager.mainObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];

  return results;
}

- (NSArray*)unfinishedEpisodesSortedByAge {
  NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];

  return [self unfinishedEpisodes:@[ sortDescriptor ]];
}
```

The part of me that would do as much as possible in SQL has a hard time thinking option 1 is better, but most of what I've read seems to indicate using the (NSSet*)episodes is extremely cheap once the podcast object comes into existence. My understanding of how Core data faults get handled in these situations is pretty shaky, and I realize Core data shouldn't really be compared to a SQL database. Simply based on how the two options are constructed, though, I would think there's some benefit to baking the predicate and sortdescriptors right into the fetch; but maybe it's not enough to make up for the gains that set provided by the relationship give.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First code will be inefficient when working with large result sets as it operates on in memory objects. All objects have to be loaded into memory, so If they aren't already there, they will be loaded *one by one* as faults are raised.

Second code will do everything on sql side and give You already filtered and sorted results. CoreData also uses internal caching to optimize such queries, so I would prefer this option if episodes aren't already loaded somewhere else. Enable CoreData debug to see how sql queries will look. [There is already an answer how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822906/how-do-i-get-the-coredata-debug-argument-to-output-to-the-console).

Comment: +1.  Option 2 is almost certainly the best approach.  You can also apply batching to the results and perhaps use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to manage any display of the podcasts.  I currently have about 1000+ unplayed podcasts in my player of choice so unless you know you are always going to be working with small numbers then option 2 is best.

Comment: Ok, so to expand on this. Lets say I have a tableview of all unfinished episodes, sorted by age, grouped by Podcast. In that case, say you're checking against [thePodcast unfinishedEpisodesSortedByAge] for the cells in each section, would it be better for each call to be doing the core data fetch? Or would it be better if [Episode allUnfinishedEpisodes] were only loaded once (implicitly or explicitly) and the filtering it down to just the receiver's episodes were done in code?

Comment: @farski In UITableView you should definitely use NSFetchedResultController, so You will need to filter records using NSPredicate. UITableView used with NSFetchedResultController will use batch queries (`setBatchSize:`) and app will be more efficient and will consume much less memory. When using sections in tableviews remember to not use dynamic properties (sections should be pre-stored in core data).