# NSFetchRequest - Includes Pending Changes

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having issues with my NSFetchedResultsController, which seem to be fixed by turning IncludesPendingChanges on, and this worries me. **(I've found this to not be true, including pending changes does not help.)**

What happens is that my Fetched Results Controller correctly fetches and displays my objects on a full API refresh. Stepping through, I have confirmed that this full API refresh's temporary context is saved and merged without error.

However, if I then return to a view which does this same fetch request from a different navigation flow, only one partially complete object is returned and displayed, rather than the complete set of objects. If I then do a full API Refresh at this point, the refresh displays the correct objects.

I believe my issue may be that mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification is not propagating to the main context, but from my logs and stepping through, it seems to me that it is saving correctly. I'm not sure where to go from here. While IncludesPendingChanges fixes the symptom, I don't believe it fixes the underlying issue.

As some added information, I'm using this framework for my Core Data Management: https://github.com/vokalinteractive/CoreDataManager-iOS

I am turning on includesPendingChanges by adding on line 156 of VIFetchedResultsController.m

```
 [fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES]
```

**Edit** Whatever fluke caused me to believe includesPendingChanges to YES fixed the problem is no longer present. Turns out this project had some seriously hairy memory management, and after spending all day cleaning that up, I'm still not closer to making this work. Still at the same point though, it looks like the changes are not propagating to the main datastore, or aren't sticking.

As a hint, like I mentioned in my comment below, even when I specify "includePendingChanges:YES", Logging out my fetched objects with:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects description]
```

ends with "includesPendingChanges: NO". Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: Have you tried [enabling core data debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822906/how-do-i-get-the-coredata-debug-argument-to-output-to-the-console) to see what queries are being run and what data is being saved/returned? Otherwise, I'd guess you're right that it's saving or threading related; perhaps you could post some code you're using around that area?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at this tomorrow!

Comment: That helped me solve my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you got it the wrong way round. The default of `includesPendingChanges` is `YES`, as this is the behavior you usually want. That your UI updates getting corrupted is sort of expected.

Setting this attribute to `NO` is really just meant to facilitate fetches with `NSDictionaryResultType`, especially when including simple aggregations that can be dealt with on the database level.

I suspect this is by no means an error by you, but a possible flaw of the framework you are using. Anyway, what you identify as an issue, is really just expected behavior.

See the two short paragraphs in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-SW5) where this is explained quite well.

Comment: Huh. I just looked at the documentation and you're right. That's just weird then. Logging "[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects description]" ends with "includesPendingChanges: NO", unless I call "[fetchRequest setIncludesPendingChanges:YES]". As if it were defaulting to NO.

Comment: I'm updating my question. I'm still confused.

Comment: OK, it really seems your framework is the problem. The problem you describe could really be anything, hidden deeply in the intricacies of a proprietary third-party framework. Quite typically, once something like this happens, it serves to increase complexity, not reduce it. Ditch CoreDatamanager-iOS and use the native API.

Comment: The third party framework is only like 3 classes, couple hundred lines a piece, and I use them everywhere. I'd rather fix the issue with the Framework then start from scratch. The framework works everywhere else too, I'm worried that the programmer I inherited the project from was using it improperly. Thanks though.